# Crash log partially symbolicated

Tags: ios, crash-reports, symbolicate

I have this crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x80000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b6d7584 0x3b6d4000 + 13700
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b6d7fa0 0x3b6d4000 + 16288
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b6d91e2 0x3b6d4000 + 20962
3   CoreFoundation                  0x339e1750 0x3391f000 + 796496
4   CoreFoundation                  0x339e149c 0x3391f000 + 795804
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b6dca46 0x3b6d4000 + 35398
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b129118 0x3b128000 + 4376
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b1291b0 0x3b128000 + 4528
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b12a626 0x3b128000 + 9766
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b6dc9b0 0x3b6d4000 + 35248
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3392829c 0x3391f000 + 37532
11  CoreFoundation                  0x339280c4 0x3391f000 + 37060
12  GraphicsServices                0x37507336 0x37502000 + 21302
13  UIKit                           0x358442b4 0x357ed000 + 357044
14  tkNails                         0x000104d2 main (main.m:16)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3bb09b1c 0x3bb08000 + 6940
```

.....

As you can see, the code related to my app (tkNails) is correctly symbolicated. However the code related to libraries/frameworks is not. I've seen other post with the opposite problem, frameworks code correctly symbolicated while app code not. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be right, unfortunately I can't borrow an iPhone 5 right now. As soon as I can test I will confirm this. Thanks

Comment: As @Kerni stated, the solution for this question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321684/crash-log-does-not-symbolicate-system-libraries-armv7s